# To use or not to use join() method with infinite loops

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, infinite-loop

Suppose an object X is supposed to run forever. X is running threads with infinite loops inside, so the program will never exit.

My question is this: is it a good practice to put use the join() method at all, for example, in the deconstructor, or would it make more sense to do something like

```
int main() {
   X myX;
   while(1) {
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Are there any differences between the two approaches?

Comment: I think it is bad practice to assume the program can, or should, run forever.  I have hardware-monitoring threads that loop, but I have a thread-abort mechanism so I can shut down gracefully.

Comment: I think it is bad practice to assume the program can, or should, run forever' - wrong.

Comment: Why so? In embedded applications this is the case most of the time.

Comment: @Bob - don't worry about it.  Try to design your app so that if the power is suddenly removed, (embedded), or your process is suddenly killed, (desktop/server), it can run/recover in an acceptable manner when run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is required, often it is not.  If you can design your app so that it does not, so much the better.

Comment: thanks for the comment. When you say 'sometimes it is required, sometime it is not' are you referring to the join() function or to the while(1) inside the main?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to call `join()` if some part of your program needed to wait to run until a thread exited.  It also makes the thread object destroyable so you don't create a memory leak.    Threads that haven't been joined are like zombie processes and waste resources.

Comment: sure, but for embedded devices or even micro controller, I've seen the while(1) quite often within the 'main' program. Hence, my question.

Comment: App-lifetime threads don't always, (ie. hardly ever), need explicit termination and cleanup.

Comment: @chicks my question is about cases where the thread itself never ends because the app is supposed to run forever. so even the join() would wait forever isn't it?

Comment: @bob Right.  But you asked about good practice.  To me part of good practice is expecting things to go wrong.  It wouldn't take much code to avoid a potential -- even if highly unlikely -- problem down the road.